# Read node from CSV file and save using batch - Drupal 7

Tags: php, csv, drupal, drupal-7, batch-processing

When I'm trying to save a node using batch processing, I'm getting this error:

> PDOException: in drupal_write_record() (line 7383 of C:\wamp64\www\drupal7\includes\common.inc).

Here is my complete code:

```
function custom_node_import_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $csvFile = file_load($form_state['values']['csv_file']);
  $csvFilepath = drupal_realpath($csvFile->uri);
  $file = fopen($csvFilepath, "r");

  $batch = array(
    'operations' => array(),
    'finished' => 'node_import_finished',
    'title' => t('Node import'),
    'init_message' => t('Importing is starting...'),
    'progress_message' => t('Imported @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message' => t('Node importer has encountered an error.')
  );

  fgetcsv($file, 0, ",");
  while($line = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $batch['operations'][] = array('node_import_progress', array(array_map('base64_encode', $line)));
  }

  batch_set($batch);
  batch_process('admin/node/custom-node-import');
  fclose($file);
}

function node_import_progress($line, &$context) {
  $line = array_map('base64_decode', $line);
  saveNode($line);
  $context['message'] = t('Importing %title', array('%title' => $line[0]));
}

function node_import_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  if ($success) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Node importing is complete!'));
  }
  else {
    $error_operation = reset($operations);
    $message = t('An error occurred while processing %error_operation with arguments: @arguments', array(
      '%error_operation' => $error_operation[0],
      '@arguments' => print_r($error_operation[1], TRUE)
    ));
    drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
  }
}
function saveNode($param = []) {
  global $user;

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->title = $param[0];
  $node->type = "article";
  node_object_prepare($node);
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->uid = $user->uid; 
  $node->status = 1;
  $node->promote = 0;
  $node->comment = 1;      
  $node->body[$node->language][]['value'] = $param[3];

  $node = node_submit($node);
  node_save($node);
}
```

I have debugged and found that the line which gives this error is the last line where the node is getting saved. i.e **node_save($node);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the non-English characters in the CSV file like ö, ä etc

So the solution was to use [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) for the values:

```
$node->title = utf8_encode($param[0]);
$node->body[$node->language][]['value'] = utf8_encode($param[3]);
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a convert for all values like this :

```
array_walk($param, function(&$value){
  $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($value));
});
```